# Selecting HTML page values using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to figure this out for a few hour and it is doing my head in. Every method I try is not presenting the correct value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/products/omia065s188000160100')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

I want to extract the following values from the webpage (https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/products/omia065s188000160100)

```
Name = LOW 3.0 SNEAKER
Price = £ 415
img_url = https://cdn.off---white.com/images/156365/large_OMIA065S188000160100_4.jpg?1498202305
```

How would I extract these 3 values using Beautiful Soup?

Comment: This link directs to a _i'm not a robot_ page.

Comment: Ah that would be due to your IP being flagged by their services.

Comment: show your every method

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get prod name
r = requests.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/products/omia065s188000160100')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'prod-title'})
data = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
prod_name = ''.join(data)

# Find prod price
spans = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'price'})
data = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
prod_price = ''.join(data)

# Find prod img
spans = soup.find_all('img', {'id' : 'image-0'})

for meta in spans:
    prod_img = meta.attrs['src']

print(prod_name)
print(prod_price)
print(prod_img)
```

Comment: you can choose your own answer. there are even badges to reward this behavior